# How to initiate forEach function inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I would like to run a function on the `ng-repeat` that takes the value of Qprogress object in my JSON and converts it to a percentage. I have the function written correctly, but I can't figure out how to initiate it. I tried to wrap it in a forEach inside the scope and then use the scope as the ng-model of the element I want to modify, but its not working. 
Here's the HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in clients" progressCalc>
    <td>
        <a href="#/details/{{clients.indexOf(item)}}" title="Link to {{item.FirstName}} {{item.LastName}}" class="oly-open">{{item.FirstName}} {{item.LastName}}</a>
    </td>
    <td ng-hide="item.Progress == 'In Progress'" ng-class="{ 'status-success': item.Progress == 'Questionnaire Completed', 'status-error': item.Progress == 'Unsent'}">
        {{item.Progress}}
    </td>
    <td ng-if="item.Progress == 'In Progress'" ng-model="progressCalc" class="status-info percent">
        {{item.Qprogress}}
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
        <a href="#/reports/" title{{$index + 1}}="Reports" ng-show="{{item.Progress == 'Questionnaire Completed'}}">
            <span class="stat-icon-report"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#/sends/{{$index + 1}}" title="Alert" ng-show="{{item.Progress == 'Unsent'}}">
            <span class="stat-icon-bullhorn"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#/progress/{{$index + 1}}" title="In Progress" ng-show="{{item.Progress == 'In Progress'}}">
            <span class="stat-icon-phone"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the JS:

```
myApp.controller('clientStatus', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('assets/js/lib/angular/clientList.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.clients = data;

        $scope.progressCalc = function() {
            angular.forEach(function(item) {
                var m = 0.26664;
                var s = 0.26664;
                var i = 0.694375;
                var t = item.Qprogress;
                t = t.replace(/m/g,'');
                t = t.replace(/s/g,'');
                t = t.replace(/i/g,'');
                var ta = t.split("/");
                var tTotal = (ta[0] * m) + (ta[1] * s) + (ta[2] * i);
                tTotal = Math.round(tTotal);
                $('.percent').append(tTotal + '%');
            });
        };
    });
}]);
```

And a snippet of the JSON formatting:

```
"FirstName": "Bill",
"LastName": "Johnson",
"Company": "Texas Instruments",
"CompanyId": "2345672",
"ClientId": "EFTGE6",
"Title": "CIO",
"Phone": "555-555-5555",
"ClientSystemStatus": "Active",
"CreationDate": "06/03/2015, 10:35:59 am",
"Progress": "In Progress",
"Qprogress": "m125/s40/i0",
"Email": "bjohson@ti.com"
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's not how `angular.forEach` works. First parameter is the iterable, second is the function, third is context. In your case you want `angular.forEach($scope.clients, function(item) { ... });`
Also is this just for display? Might want to consider using a filter instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you need to calculate, but I think that the `forEach` is not required. So I did some changes/fixes, take a look.

Controller:

```
$http.get('assets/js/lib/angular/clientList.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.clients = data;
});

$scope.progressCalc = function(item) {
    var m = 0.26664;
    var s = 0.26664;
    var i = 0.694375;
    var t = item.Qprogress;
    t = t.replace(/m/g,'');
    t = t.replace(/s/g,'');
    t = t.replace(/i/g,'');
    var ta = t.split("/");
    var tTotal = (ta[0] * m) + (ta[1] * s) + (ta[2] * i);
    tTotal = Math.round(tTotal);
    return tTotal + '%';
};
```

HTML:

pay attention to the first line: I removed the wrong directive call `progressCalc`.
And more below, just as example, I call the method `progressCalc` printing the result.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in clients">
    <td>
        <a href="#/details/{{clients.indexOf(item)}}" title="Link to {{item.FirstName}} {{item.LastName}}" class="oly-open">{{item.FirstName}} {{item.LastName}}</a>
    </td>
    <td ng-hide="item.Progress == 'In Progress'" ng-class="{ 'status-success': item.Progress == 'Questionnaire Completed', 'status-error': item.Progress == 'Unsent'}">
        {{item.Progress}}
    </td>
    <td ng-if="item.Progress == 'In Progress'" class="status-info percent">
        {{item.Qprogress}} {{progressCalc(item)}}
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
        <a href="#/reports/" title{{$index + 1}}="Reports" ng-show="{{item.Progress == 'Questionnaire Completed'}}">
            <span class="stat-icon-report"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#/sends/{{$index + 1}}" title="Alert" ng-show="{{item.Progress == 'Unsent'}}">
            <span class="stat-icon-bullhorn"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#/progress/{{$index + 1}}" title="In Progress" ng-show="{{item.Progress == 'In Progress'}}">
            <span class="stat-icon-phone"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I didn't tested it, but should be works or help!

Comment: You rock! I will try the above as well, but in a rush to get this done and I needed a quick fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach it, especially if your calculation only needs to happen once per item, is to run the method from your controller as a callback.

```
$http.get('assets/js/lib/angular/clientList.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.clients = data;
    $scope.clients.forEach(function(client) {
         //your calculations here.
    });
});
```

If you really need to run the code from the html then you I would refer to the answer left by @manzapanza